# Trouble running jetty servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I managed to follow some tutorial and setup a jetty webserver that runs with Maven in Intellij. It runs when I click into maven and do Jetty:run but does not run from my main class. My issue is when try and run the code to launch a webserver I get an error that says Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toURI()" because "webAppDir" is null. I tried looking at different tutorials but they all use the same structure I set my project up with but they do not encounter this error.

[image]

I don't know why it's pointing to a null directory for me but it worked for them, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using Jetty 9.4.28.

[Jetty 9.4.x is at End of Community Support](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/7958)

You should be upgrading your version of Jetty.

Looking at your code, you are attempting to get a resource by referencing a directory, not a file.

```java
URL webAppDir = Driver.class.getClassLoader().getResource("META-INF/resources");
```

That's an unreliable technique to reference content in your classloader, as that API prefers that you reference a file, not a directory.

Try referencing a file in that directory, and then stripping it off to use it.

Example from [embedded-jetty-cookbook `DefaultServletFileServer.java`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook/blob/jetty-10.0.x/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/cookbook/DefaultServletFileServer.java)

```java
// Figure out what path to serve content from
ClassLoader cl = DefaultServletFileServer.class.getClassLoader();
// We look for a file, as ClassLoader.getResource() is not
// designed to look for directories (we resolve the directory later)
URL f = cl.getResource("static-root/hello.html");
if (f == null)
{
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to find resource directory");
}

// Resolve file to directory
URI webRootUri = f.toURI().resolve("./").normalize();
System.err.println("WebRoot is " + webRootUri);

context.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(webRootUri));
```